# How to add to a config file within a snakemake pipeline and define global variables?

Tags: snakemake

I am new to snakemake and am trying to create a pipeline that would have a sample file in the config. A rule would parse this file and pull out certain information that is needed by the pipeline. So I would like to add this to the config file or create global variables is this possible?or to force it to wait for the rule to finish before defining config file or variable?

I have tried adding to a config file using a rule with shell cat command. But it doesn't try to run as the output is the config file. Also tried declaring config file after rule but It doesn't matter on order. Also tried to touch the output file as part of the rule

```
include:"fastqc.snake"

IDS, = glob_wildcards("testdata/samples/{id}.fastq.gz")

rule all:
    input:  expand("fastqc_reports/{id}_fastqc.html", id=IDS)

rule add:
    input:
        "test_in.txt" 
    output:
        "config.yaml"
    shell:
       "cat {input} >> {output}"


configfile: "config.yaml"
```

I would like the contents of the input file to be appended to the config file. In reality it will be a number of variables I find in the input file. OR I would like to be able to create global variables based on the parsing of the input file.

Comment: Taking a step back, does you piepline work as expected if you remove `rule add` and provide `config.yaml` directly to snakemake? You might want to [check `onstart`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#onstart-onsuccess-and-onerror-handlers). Note that, `onstart` doesn't get triggered for dryruns.

Comment: Another suggestion: Instead of defining it as a rule, you might be better off using a typical python function for what `rule add` is doing.

Comment: yes it works without the add rule. My issue is that I want to be able to add to the existing config file. Or instead of doing this, be able to run a python script that sets global variables in my snakemake script from it's input. so something like 

rule add_vars: 
input: test_in.txt
output: dummy_file
shell: python parseFile.py --input test_in.txt 

with parseFile.py setting global variables

Comment: I doubt if either `run` or `shell` would allow doing what you are asking. Since snakemake allows lot of python stuff, how about this: `from parseFile import fn_get_variables; x,y,z=fn_get_variables()`. Of course, `fn_get_variables` could be part of snakemake script itself as well.

Comment: Thank you. I ended up altering my config file and then creating the variables directly from that at initiation of the snakemake run.